# How do you change a table's schema?

Tags: mysql-workbench

We have a MySQL Workbench project with two tabs (two schemas/two databases).

- If we create a table in the first tab, it's attached to the schema
  `magikweb_dev_igcweb`.
- If we create a table in the second tab, it's attached to the schema
  `magikweb_dev_igcweb_archive`.

**If we copy-paste/duplicate a table from the first tab to the second tab, the resulting table remains in the first schema. How can you change a table's schema?**

Each schema is linked with a specific database, so when we use the "Synchronize Model..." feature, it links all the tables properly.

[image: Visual support]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the model tab. You can cut out a table from one schema tab and insert it into another.

Comment: For anyone wondering, it's the first tab at the top of the provided screenshot. The schemas' tables are distinct from the model figures.

Comment: I did the cut and paste, Now the tables are missing from the EER Diagram. Help needed on how to get them back

Comment: I just dragged and dropped them to my EER Diagram from the catalogs. Phew.

Comment: Unfortunately when I use this method, foreign key relationships between the tables are lost. (MySQL Workbench 6.3)

Comment: Foreign keys are lost and I can't do what @VarunRao suggested, because the Catalogs do not refresh...

Answer (score 7):

The cut-and-paste method described in another answer works well for tables with no foreign keys, and for a reasonable number of tables.

An alternative that preserves foreign keys is to export the model as a SQL script, edit it, and then import the new script into a new model.

Using MySQL Workbench v6.3:

1. File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL Script
2. Carefully edit SQL script. Replace references to one schema with the other, for the tables you want to move. Do this both for CREATE TABLE commands and foreign key references.
3. File -> New Model
4. File -> Import -> Reverse Engineer SQL Script

Unfortunately you will then need to recreate any diagrams. But that can be straightforward if you have the original diagram as reference (take a screenshot or export it to PNG or PDF.)

Answer (score 2):

**Follow this simple steps (never miss step 4 and 5) :**

1. **Open Model Tab**
2. **Choose source schema**. In my case, I want to copy `table users` from schema `abc_develop_v1` to schema `abc_develop_v2` then paste to diagram . So I choose schema `abc_develop_v1`, **right-click `table users` then Copy 'users'**
3. **Go to the targeted schema**. In my case is schema `abc_develop_v2`, **right-click then Paste 'users'**
4. Next, copy `table users` from schema `abc_develop_v2`. **Right-click `table users` then Copy 'users'**
5. Go to your diagram and **Paste 'users'**.

**That's all. Your table is ready in your diagram with the right `schema`  :-)**

> **Notes:** You can double check by double-click on the table in your diagram, and look at the right corner. It will show the `Schema` name.

Answer (score 0):

I found a less painful way to do this.

0. Save and backup your diagram and your schema.
1. Display schema's name before table's names in diagram. This will make the next step easier.
   [image]
2. Right-click on the tables which are on the wrong schema, and select "Copy SQL to clipboard". Paste the script in a new SQL window. Repeat for each table you want to migrate.
   [image]
3. Edit the script to change the schema name. Watch for any miss in entries, the wrong schema might be a reference at any line. Mine was `mydb`, which I don't remember creating. Execute the script. Now you have the tables on the right schema.
   [image]
4. Synchronize your model. Be sure to check "Update the model" for each missing table, otherwise, the tables will be deleted from the schema :)

[image]

5. Drag'n'drop the newly created tables into the diagram. Then remove the ones which are using the wrong schema. Tip: tables that are not in diagram won't display a dot next to their name.
   [image]
6. Optionally, you can delete the faulty schema from the model so this never happens again. Be sure to know what you're doing first!

[image]